# Centralizar um div com texto e position absolute no centro da div pai

Tags: css, posicionamento

Gente é o seguinte eu tenho uma div pai e uma outra div com um texto em position absolute... esse texto esta alinhado ao top e a esquerda da div pai e eu preciso alinhar ao centro... coisas como top: x% ou left x% .. n funcionam pois o elemento pai é dinamico e responsivo ...preciso que fique mesmo ao centro .. tentei coisas como justify content e align items no centro mas não adiantou.. alguem sabe como... segue o codigo da div :

```
.textotoposobre{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 30%;
    left: 28%;
}
```

Comment: Um site muito útil para aprender como centralizar elementos e texto em CSS é o <a href="http://howtocenterincss.com/">howtocenterincss.com</a>. Ele permite escolher a altura e largura do elemento, o alinhamento do conteúdo e que versões do internet explorer você precisa que o código funcione.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada obg

Answer (score 5):

Criando uma `div` pai com `position: relative`, e a `div` filho com `position: absolute` devem resolver o seu problema, desde que a `div` filho esteja posicionada a uma distância equivalente à 50% do container (`div` pai) menos a metade do seu próprio tamanho. Essa distância deve valer tanto para cima quanto para à esquerda. Isto pode ser realizado da seguinte maneira:

```
.filho{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Veja que, desta maneira, o tamanho da `div` pai não interessa.

```css
.filho{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pai{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: aqua; 
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
    <div class="filho">Texto texto texto</div>
</div>
```

Experimente alterar o tamanho da `div` pai para entender o comportamento.

Comment: obrigado vou tentar aqui

Answer (score 0):

Na div do texto coloque `**margin: 0 auto;**`

Comment: Penso que como tem `position: absolute;` não vai centrar nada.